# Use CXF client api with Java web application

Tags: web-services, servlets, web-applications, tomcat7, cxf-client

How to consume Web service suing Apache CXF client API. 
I have generated the client Code using eclispe but I didn't found any document specifying how to use that generated code in my web application.

How to configure CXF? I am using tomcat to run my java web appliation.
How to use the generated code? 
Do I need to add anyhting in my my web.xml?

I have downloaded CXF binaries from apache CXF website but don't know which libraries are needed. I am affraid i may end up adding all the jars.

I am using Tomcat 7, Java 1.6 and plane jsp/Servlet for my application

I am new to web services.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One sample code that may help.

```
URL wsdlurl=SOAPWebServiceTransport.class.getClassLoader().
                getResource("my.wsdl");
// MyService will be one of the service class that you have generated (with different name ofcourse)and which must be extending Service class
//getOnlineServicePort will be a method (with different name ofcourse) in your service class which will give you the interface referrer using which you'll call the webservice method 
OnlinePort service= new MyService(wsdlurl).getOnlineServicePort();
Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
//configure security user name password as required
//Add interceptors if needed
//Now you can directly call the webservice methods using the service object
service.method(parameter)
```

you can also refer to some example one is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html)